# Retrieve stock "change in percentage" in google spreadsheet with ImportXML()

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api, xml-import

I would like to retrieve stock data on Google Spreadsheet through the ImportXML() function.

Suppose I want to retrieve stock data of `SHA:000001`
To retrieve price, the formula to use is;

```
=ImportXML("https://www.google.com/finance?q=SHA:000001", "//span[@class='pr']")
```

What is the formula to use for retrieving "price change in percentage" for the day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
=ImportXML("https://www.google.com/finance?q=SHA:000001", "//div[@class='id-price-change nwp']/span/span[2]")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Almost correct. The output is (-6.86%). How can the brackets be removed?

Comment: Another thing that puzzles me. How did you get the html code so neatly formatted? When I view the page source, the code looks jumbled up.

Comment: If you look at the Chrome Developer Tools, the source is always formatted.